# cvs2hg configuration in windows

Tags: cvs, dvcs, cvs2svn

We are planning to migrate complex cvs repository with history to Mercurial.

I have configured cvs2hg in my local machine and cvs(pserver)has installed in remote server. 
I am facing below errors while I migrating code from remote cvs repository to local mercurial repository using cvs2hg(local).

```
D:\cvs2svn\cvs2svn-19b322d42b1f>python cvs2hg --hgrepos=C:\Users\smandadapu2\De
ktop\mercuryy C:\Users\smandadapu2\Desktop\CVS_Checkout\CVSROOT
----- pass 1 (CollectRevsPass) -----
Examining all CVS ',v' files...
ERROR: No RCS files found under 'C:\\Users\\smandadapu2\\Desktop\\CVS_Checkout\
CVSROOT'!
Are you absolutely certain you are pointing cvs2svn
at a CVS repository?

Pass 1 complete.
===========================================================================
Error summary:
ERROR: No RCS files found under 'C:\\Users\\smandadapu2\\Desktop\\CVS_Checkout\
CVSROOT'!
Are you absolutely certain you are pointing cvs2svn
at a CVS repository?

Exited due to fatal error(s).**strong text**
```

Please help me on configuring cvs2hg on windows with detailed

1. How to specify the remote cvs repository path while using cvs2hg ?
2. How to specify the cvs repository modules while using cvs2hg ?
3. what are the things should be taken care for complete history migration?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to start your conversion from a checked-out version ("working copy") of your repository. `cvs2hg` needs the whole repository with all of its history as input. That's what is usually stored on a remote server, and includes a lot of files with names like `<filename>,v`. You have to get a copy of the repository, and then run `cvs2hg` against it.